# spring and junit4 to test a private method in class

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot

I have two spring bean class ServiceA and ServiceB. ServiceA dependents ServiceB. Show the code:

```
@Service // spring IOC annotation
public class ServiceA {

   @Autowired
   private ServiceB sb;

   // other code
   
   private void aMethod() {
      // other code
      sb.bMethod();
      // other code
   }

}
```

I write the ServiceA`s unit class by Junit4, flowing code:

```
@SpringBootTest
@RunWith(SpringRunner.class)
public class ServiceATest {

   @Autowired
   private ServiceA sa;

   @Test
   public void aMethodTest() {
        Method method = ReflectionUtils.findMethod(ServiceA.class, "aMethod");
        method.setAccessible(true);
        ReflectionUtils.invokeMethod(method, sa);
   }
}
```

I run the ServiceATest, when I debug the ServiceATest#aMethodTest(), the object 'sa' is a CGLIB proxy object. But I debug the ServiceA#aMethod(), the 'sb' is null.

I am confused. The object 'sa' is from Spring Bean Container, so it must be a complete object with Spring-DI. Why it`s field is null when i call sa.aMethod() method?

Comment: because you are calling it on a proxy instead of the real object. Also you shouldn't be testing private methods, test the actual public method that invokes that private method.

Comment: Thanks.But I have other question: why not recommend testing private method? Or do I have a wrong idea about "private method"?

Comment: Because they are private and are not meant to be called directly. They are being called as part of a public method. The public method is the one you should be testing and probably with different input/scenario's so that you test all permutation possible.

Answer (score 0):

Not the answer you may be looking for, but private methods are supposed to be supporter methods and not need to be tested. Incase if you have written private method that needs unit test then PowerMock or PowerMockito will provide much better tests than java reflection.

Comment: Thanks for your answer.
PowerMock or PowerMockito can simulation static/final/private method. But I want to test private method. So Why not test private method directly?Maybe I have a wrong idea about "private method“？

Comment: The reason for private method to exist is that it has restricted access. It has a reason to have access at class level only, that means responsibility of that method doesn't matter to anything outside of class. 
As for PowerMock or PowerMockito doesn't only simulate those methods they can actually can call it. But I would still say if you are writing unit test for private method than you are writing your code wrong. Private methods are supposed to be supporter methods and should not need testing. A test for method that calls private method should cover that private method.